# Why can't I hover the following fixed elements?

Tags: html, css

To illustrate:

[image]

CSS of `.chapter-list`:

```
.chapter-list,
.chapter-actions,
.chapter-words,
.current-book-actions {
visibility: hidden;
}
.chapter-list:hover,
.chapter-actions:hover,
.chapter-words:hover,
.current-book-actions:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
.chapter-list {
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
left: 30px;
top: 30px;
}
```

No matter what z-index I use, I'm unable to hover `.chapter-list`. `.container` doesn't have any CSS at all so I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

**EDIT:**

This is the CSS for `.chapter-form`:

```
.chapter-form {
margin: 30px auto 0;
width: 45%;
max-width: 640px;
}
```

Not sure how it could be affecting the hover, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hover it because you have hidden it with `visiblity: hidden`.

```
.chapter-list,
.chapter-actions,
.chapter-words,
.current-book-actions {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Hidden elements still take up space in the document, but you can't see them or interact with them. This is why you can still see the space the element is using in the developer tools.

Edit - assuming you want to have the element initially hidden then have it appear on hover (which seems like a really strange interaction), you could do this:

```
.chapter-list,
.chapter-actions,
.chapter-words,
.current-book-actions {
    opacity: 0;
}

.chapter-list:hover,
.chapter-actions:hover,
.chapter-words:hover,
.current-book-actions:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: @alexchenco Why are you hiding it? You can just remove that CSS if you don't want the element to be hidden.

Comment: What I want to do is to hide a tool bar and only show it when the user hovers the area. So he can have a distraction free environment.